# Key health metrics for Apache Flink

Tags: monitoring, apache-flink

I'm trying to figure out what are the key health metrics for Apache Flink.
Flink documentation provides huge list of metrics and it's hard to figure out important ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some suggestions:

If you are using Kafka, the Kafka client metrics are forwarded into Flink's metric system. Monitoring consumer lag will let you know if your job is failing to keep up with the inflow of data.

If your job is failing to make progress, looking at the `currentLowWatermark` can help you determine which task(s) are holding back progress.

It's smart to keep an eye on checkpointing. `lastCheckpointDuration`, `lastCheckpointSize`, and `numberOf{Completed,Failed,InProgress}Checkpoints` are useful here.

`uptime` and `downtime` can help you track how much time your job is spending in recovery as opposed to actually running.

The community has recently been discussing how we might do a better job of detecting backpressure. You'll find [that discussion in the dev mailing list archives](http://apache-flink-mailing-list-archive.1008284.n3.nabble.com/DISCUSS-Detection-Flink-Backpressure-td26149.html).

Comment: Hi @david-anderson, I'm recently having issue with a Flink job and I'm not sure about our lastCheckpointSize. What is considered a checkpoint size 'too big' ?
Our cluster is frequently going down and we are not entirely sure why. The lastCheckpointSize is around 4GB and the duration is ~30second with sometimes peak to 4-5 minutes